# Azure application gateway redirect configuration

Tags: powershell, azure

I've created a power-shell script that adds redirect configuration to external site in the Azure application gateway service.

```
$AppgwName = "appgwname"
$rgName = "rgname"
$Externalsite = "http://www.google.com"
$RedirectConfigurationName = "name of the redirect config"
$listnerName = "listner name"
$redirectrulename = "existing rule name "

$gw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name $AppgwName -ResourceGroupName 
$rgName
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name 
$RedirectConfigurationName -RedirectType Temporary -TargetUrl $Externalsite 
-ApplicationGateway $gw
$defaultListener = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name 
$listnerName -ApplicationGateway $gw
$redirectConfig = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name 
$RedirectConfigurationName -ApplicationGateway $gw
$redirectRule =  Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -Name 
$redirectrulename -RuleType Basic -HttpListener $defaultListener - 
RedirectConfiguration $redirectConfig -ApplicationGateway $gw
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw
```

the script works well! !  ! but when i try to remove the configuration i encountered an error.

```
$gw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name $AppgwName -ResourceGroupName 
$rgName
$gw = Remove-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name 
$RedirectConfigurationName -ApplicationGateway $gw
Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -Name $redirectrulename - 
RuleType Basic -HttpListener $defaultListener -ApplicationGateway $gw - 
BackendAddressPool $backendpool
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw
```

[Error ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EPj1.png)

don't know if my removal script is configured properly, please help me to solve this.

Thanks :)

Comment: someone can assist?

Comment: what i can tell you is that "Remove" option doesn't appear in Azure portal, so maybe this option isn't available. Maybe you need to change it instead of removing?